# C# Socket ErrorCode 10054 on Client Refresh Connection

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

I've been attempting to write a communication layer utilizing TCP for an application that I am building. I control both server and client side operations.

The problem that I am running in to is that when I use 'localhost' as my IP, I have no problems. However, when I connect using the internet, everything works magically...the first time. When the client attempts to build another socket connection to the server, I get SocketException ErrorCode 10054 on the server side, during ReadCallback, specifically when I perform a socket.EndReceive operation.

I have already looked at the possibility that my sockets are not getting disposed properly - they sure should be, as I cannot see a path out of the client or server side application which doesn't lead to a close.

My code fairly closely resembles code from MSDN, which can be found [here (server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here (client)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is the relevant parts of my client code:

```
public class ClientStateObject
{
    // Client socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[Constants.ClientBuffer];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public List<byte[]> Data = new List<byte[]>();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{

    // ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);

    // The response from the remote device.
    private static byte[] response = null;

    public static object StartClient(object sendObj)
    {
        // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
            // Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
            // The name of the 
            // remote device is ...
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Constants.Hostname); // localhost
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Constants.Port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);



            LingerOption lo = new LingerOption(false, 0);
            client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, lo);



            // Connect to the remote endpoint.
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();

            // Send test data to the remote device.
            object[] s;
            s = new object[2] { sendObj, "<EOF>" };
            Send(client, s);
            sendDone.WaitOne();

            // Receive the response from the remote device.
            Receive(client);
            receiveDone.WaitOne();

            // Write the response to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response);
            //Console.ReadKey();


            // Release the socket.
            client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);

            client.Close();


            //object res = Deserialize(Deserialize(response) as byte[]);
            object res = Deserialize(Deserialize(response) as byte[]);
            return res;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e;
        }
    }

    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete the connection.
            client.EndConnect(ar);

            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

            // Signal that the connection has been made.
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the state object.
            ClientStateObject state = new ClientStateObject();
            state.workSocket = client;

            // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, Constants.ClientBuffer, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the state object and the client socket 
            // from the asynchronous state object.
            ClientStateObject state = (ClientStateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.workSocket;

            // Read data from the remote device.
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                // There might be more data, so store the data received so far.
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                state.Data.Add(state.buffer); // Concat byte[] to received packet

                // Get the rest of the data.
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, Constants.ClientBuffer, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                // All the data has arrived; put it in response.
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = ConcatByteListToArray(state.Data);
                }
                // Signal that all bytes have been received.
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static byte[] ConcatByteListToArray(List<byte[]> b)
    {
        List<byte> bList = new List<byte>();
        foreach (byte[] bA in b)
        {
            foreach (byte by in bA)
            {
                bList.Add(by);
            }
        }

        return bList.ToArray();
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, object data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.

        byte[] byteData = Serialize(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);

            // Signal that all bytes have been sent.
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    /*
     * Function: Serialize(object obj)
     * Requires: Arbitrary object.
     * Returns: MyMessage object, which constants a byte[] (Data) representing an object in TCP-friendly form.
     * Description: Private function used to turn an object into a serialized byte[].
     */
    private static byte[] Serialize(object obj)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            (new BinaryFormatter()).Serialize(memoryStream, obj);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Function: Deserialize(MyMessage message)
     * Requires: MyMessage object with Data attribute.
     * Returns: object which was originally serialized.
     * Description: Private function used to reverse the process of "Serialize".
     */
    private static object Deserialize(byte[] message)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(message))
        {
            return (new BinaryFormatter()).Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }
```

And here are the relevant parts of the server code:

```
public class ServerStateObject
{
    // Client  socket.
    public Socket workSocket = null;
    // Receive buffer.
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[Constants.ServerBuffer];
    // Received data string.
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    public List<byte[]> Data = new List<byte[]>();
}

public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    public static bool GetDataSuccess;
    // Thread signal.
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public AsynchronousSocketListener()
    {

    }

    public static void StartListening()
    {
        // Data buffer for incoming data.
        byte[] bytes = new Byte[Constants.ServerBuffer];

        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
        // The DNS name of the computer
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".

        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, Constants.Port);

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        LingerOption lo = new LingerOption(false, 0);
        listener.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.Linger, lo);



        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen(10);

            while (true)
            {
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                allDone.Reset();

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                listener.BeginAccept(
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                    listener);

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                allDone.WaitOne();

                //Console.WriteLine("Done waiting for client.");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
        Console.Read();

    }

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        ServerStateObject state = new ServerStateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, Constants.ServerBuffer, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        ServerStateObject state = (ServerStateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;
        Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from {1} : {2}.",
                    content.Length, (handler.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Address, (handler.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Port);
        int bytesRead = 0;
        try
        {
            bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Socket Exception in Callback Read: {0}", se.ErrorCode); // I always get an error here on refresh
        }

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead)); // Check if there is an EOF in the byte[]
            state.Data.Add(state.buffer); // Concat byte[] to received packet


            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
            {
                byte[] rArray = ConcatByteListToArray(state.Data);
                byte[] sendArray = Serialize(HandleRead(rArray));
                // All the data has been read from the 
                // client. Display it on the console.
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from {1} : {2}.",
                    content.Length, (handler.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Address, (handler.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint).Port);

                // Echo the data back to the client.
                Send(handler, sendArray);
            }
            else
            {
                // Not all data received. Get more.
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, Constants.ServerBuffer, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }


        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket handler, object data)
    {
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.
        byte[] byteData = Serialize(data);

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();

            Console.WriteLine("Connection to client broken.");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I thought that the problem might be related to the way that Windows disposes of sockets, and perhaps not doing that fast enough. Unfortunately, the code doesn't work for a refresh, even if I wait a few minutes between the first and second connection.

Comment: Consider starting fresh. The MSDN sample is atrociously bad. I'm closing this because the code is simply to much to review.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to find a better example, if the MSDN one doesn't work well?

Comment: I don't have a link ready but you can search my SO posts for "socket" or "TcpClient" to find all of the common mistakes explained. It's really always the same stuff. Often instigated by MSDN. Shameful.

Comment: I have done a lot of searching in the past few days trying to fix this problem. Unfortunately, I seem to have run into a unique problem in which two simultaneous conditions exist: 1. The problem only happens on the second socket opening and 2. The problem only happens when an external connection is required (ie. not on local host). When operating on localhost, the whole program works well, so I feel like it is probably one or two bad lines, and that a complete rewrite wouldn't be required. Admittedly, I am no expert though. Very new to the world of networking.

Comment: There are a lot of static variables in this depressing sample code. That makes different connections interact. Get rid of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after a little bit more hunting through my code and reading error messages, I found that the client side was throwing an error code 10057 before going into "send". This error meant the socket wasn't open - even though the socket is supposed to wait to send until the socket is open.

So, the problem is that the events were not getting reset at the beginning of every run in the program. This wasn't a problem on localhost because the async socket was able to open before getting to a point in the send function where it needed to be open. However, when the end point was not local, it took too long, thus the error.

I simply added three lines of code to the beginning of "StartClient":

```
            connectDone.Reset();
            sendDone.Reset();
            receiveDone.Reset();
```

This fixed the whole problem.

So...always remember to set your initial variable conditions, lest you look like a fool!

Comment: Without making the variables non-static this will still be racy because multiple requests will hammer on the same events. Consider switching to sync socket IO. It does not need any events.